# Apt update failed when I using local repository

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, operation

I deployed a local `apt` repository in LAN, the server IP is `192.168.88.96`, by `apt-mirror`.
Below is the config of `/etc/apt/mirror.list`.

```
############# config ##################
#
# set base_path    /var/spool/apt-mirror
#
# set mirror_path  $base_path/mirror
# set skel_path    $base_path/skel
# set var_path     $base_path/var
# set cleanscript $var_path/clean.sh
# set defaultarch  amd64
# set postmirror_script $var_path/postmirror.sh
# set run_postmirror 0
set nthreads     20
set _tilde 0
#
############# end config ##############
deb-amd64 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb-amd64 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-i386 https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
clean https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu/
```

And this is the result after executed command `"sudo apt-mirror"` on `192.168.88.96`, and looks ok.

```
*****@source96:~$ sudo apt-mirror
Downloading 345 index files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Feb 27 09:13:01 2019
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]
.. [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Wed Feb 27 09:47:38 2019

Processing tranlation indexes: [TTTTTTTTTT]

Downloading 1116 translation files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Feb 27 09:47:38 2019
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]
.. [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]...


[0]...
End time: Wed Feb 27 10:12:22 2019

Processing indexes: [PPPPPPPPPP]

1.6 GiB will be downloaded into archive.
Downloading 394 archive files using 20 threads...
Begin time: Wed Feb 27 10:12:41 2019
[20]... [19]... [18]... [17]... [16]... [15]... [14]... [13]... [12]... [11]... [10]... [9]... [8]... [7]... [6]... [5]
.. [4]... [3]... [2]... [1]... [0]...
End time: Wed Feb 27 10:53:29 2019

0 bytes in 0 files and 0 directories can be freed.
Run /var/spool/apt-mirror/var/clean.sh for this purpose.

Running the Post Mirror script ...
(/var/spool/apt-mirror/var/postmirror.sh)


Post Mirror script has completed. See above output for any possible errors.

And this is the the setting of client computer:
deb http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu/ xenial-siecurity main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

And once I execute `"sudo apt update"`, it shows tones of problem:

```
Ign:8 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:9 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:10 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:11 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:13 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/restricted i386 Packages
Ign:15 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/restricted Translation-en
Ign:16 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:17 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/universe Translation-en
Ign:20 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:21 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:22 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign:23 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 Packages   
Ign:24 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/multiverse Translation-en  
Ign:25 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:26 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Ign:11 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
Ign:16 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/nightly/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Ign:20 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:21 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:25 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:26 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
Err:11 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
  404  Not Found
Ign:12 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
Ign:16 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:28 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages 
Ign:29 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages  
Ign:30 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:32 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:33 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 Packages  
Ign:34 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted i386 Packages   
Ign:35 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted Translation-en  
Ign:36 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:37 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages  
Ign:38 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages   
Ign:39 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe Translation-en  
Ign:40 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:41 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Ign:42 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages  
Ign:43 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse i386 Packages   
Ign:44 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse Translation-en  
Ign:45 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:46 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Ign:47 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 Packages  
Ign:48 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/main i386 Packages   
Ign:49 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/main Translation-en  
Ign:50 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:51 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Ign:52 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:53 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 Packages  
Ign:54 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe i386 Packages   
Ign:55 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe Translation-en  
Ign:56 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:57 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Ign:58 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:59 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:60 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages   
Ign:61 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 Packages
Ign:62 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/main Translation-en   
Ign:63 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:64 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
Ign:65 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 Packages 
Ign:66 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted i386 Packages  
Ign:67 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted Translation-en 
Ign:68 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:69 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 Packages   
Ign:70 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign:71 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/universe Translation-en   
Ign:72 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:73 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
Ign:74 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 Packages 
Ign:75 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse i386 Packages  
Ign:76 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse Translation-en 
Ign:77 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:78 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
Ign:79 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 Packages 
Ign:80 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main i386 Packages
Ign:81 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main Translation-en   
Ign:82 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:83 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
Ign:84 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:85 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe amd64 Packages   
Ign:86 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe i386 Packages
Ign:87 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe Translation-en   
Ign:88 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:89 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
Ign:90 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:91 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
Ign:31 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:32 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
Ign:36 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:40 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:41 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Ign:45 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:46 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:50 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:51 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:52 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:56 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:57 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:58 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:59 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:63 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:64 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
Ign:68 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:72 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:73 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:77 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:78 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Ign:82 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:83 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Ign:84 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:88 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:89 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
Ign:90 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:91 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:31 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Err:32 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
  404  Not Found
Ign:36 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:40 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:41 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
Ign:45 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:46 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
Ign:50 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Err:51 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
  404  Not Found
Ign:52 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:56 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:57 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons   
Ign:58 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata  
Ign:59 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
Ign:63 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Err:64 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
  404  Not Found
Ign:68 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:72 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:73 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:77 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:78 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-security/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:82 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Err:83 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons  
  404  Not Found
Ign:84 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/restricted amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:88 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:89 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:90 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata   
Ign:91 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:82 http://192.168.88.96/ubuntu xenial-proposed/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata 
Ign:93 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease 
Err:98 http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/nightly/ubuntu xenial Release   
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/fcitx-team/nightly/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

First of all, I think it is the problem of the third part source(Download from official source is too slow in China),  but I replaced the `source.list` file which in client computer with `"tuna"` source, to check out if the problem will appear again. But it didn't, every thing is fine, no Ign, no Err, just Hit and Get. So it should I made something wrong when deploy it.

I need some advice to solve this problem. Thank you all.

Comment: Do you really mean this? xenial-siecurity? Or is it a typo?

Comment: Well, it indeed is " xenial-siecurity"  in source.list, how silly I am.But after I fixed this problem and executed "sudo apt update", it still appeared the same promblem, tons of Ign, a few Err.

Answer (score 0):

Replace xenial-siecurity to xenial-security will help to solve your problem.

Comment: Well, it indeed is " xenial-siecurity"  in source.list, how silly I am.But after I fixed this problem and executed "sudo apt update", it still appeared the same promblem, tons of Ign, a few Err.